# What is wicket-request module for?

Tags: wicket

After some research I decided to use Apache Wicked framework to write my new application. I downloaded the distribution and found there a lot of modules along with a wicket-core. I investigated the list to find out what exactly may I need for my requirements. All is more or less clear except wicked-request. What is it for? Can somebody explain clearer, so I can decide if I really need it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the pom.xml of wicket-core, you can see that core has two main intra-project dependencies:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
  <artifactId>wicket-util</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
  <artifactId>wicket-request</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

So wicket-request is an essential module that has just been split from the core to group components dealing with client requests together.